# How to know the best color for status bar as according to the action bar color

Tags: android, material-ui, android-actionbar, material-design

ok I have changed the action bar color and status bar color to the same but it doesn't looks good and I want to get a darker color for the toolbar to make it look like how a normal status bar looks like

Here is an example of what im trying to say

[image]

how can i achieve this, I'm using #63461c for the action bar rn, what color should I go for the status bar

Comment: You want the colour code? or runtime detection of darker colour according to action bar?

Comment: both if possible so i can see which works the best

Comment: #50300E this is color code for the statusBar

Comment: hey thanks a lot , can u tell me how do you get that

Comment: Using digital color meter https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac , I get the RGB value, then converted it to Hex using https://www.rgbtohex.net